# Why does my SQL query give this error?

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out why I keep getting error #1054 - Unknown column 'Filename' in 'field list'

```
SELECT 'R' AS Type, er.ID, er.RecipeID AS RecipeID,
    RecipeName AS Name,er.Quantity,UnitID, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(PFCC,',',1) AS Protein,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PFCC,',',2),',',-1) AS Fat, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PFCC,',',-2),',',1) AS Carbs,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(PFCC,',',-1) AS Calories, 
    Rating, AvgRating, AvgCount, 0 AS SpecificID, 
    COALESCE(rimg.Filename,'0.png') AS DefaultImage, 
    s.Price, s.MaxQuantity 
FROM `event-recipe` er 
LEFT JOIN(
      SELECT r.ID,RecipeName,
          SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, 
          IFNULL(Rating,0) AS Rating
      FROM recipe r 
           LEFT JOIN(
              SELECT RecipeID, Filename 
              FROM recipe_image 
              WHERE IsDefault) rimg 
              ON r.ID=rimg.RecipeID 
           LEFT JOIN `recipe-ingredient` ri 
              ON r.ID=ri.RecipeID 
           LEFT JOIN(
              SELECT RecipeID,Rating 
              FROM `recipe-rating` 
              WHERE CustomerID=2) rr 
              on r.ID=rr.RecipeID 
     GROUP BY r.ID) r ON er.RecipeID=r.ID 
LEFT JOIN(
     SELECT RecipeID, GROUP_CONCAT(Value ORDER BY Nutr_No) AS PFCC 
     FROM nutrient_view_ingredient nv 
     WHERE Nutr_No IN (203,204,205,208) 
     GROUP BY RecipeID) n 
     ON r.ID=n.RecipeID 
LEFT JOIN sell_recipe s ON (er.EventID=s.EventID AND s.RecipeID=er.RecipeID) 
LEFT JOIN(
     SELECT RecipeID, COUNT(RecipeID) AS AvgCount, ROUND(AVG(Rating),1) AS AvgRating 
     FROM `recipe-rating` 
     GROUP BY RecipeID) avgrate 
     ON r.ID=avgrate.RecipeID 
WHERE er.EventID=53
```

Comment: I've tried putting `Filename`. I've tried renaming the column completely, thinking Filename is a reserved word in MySQL. I've tried using rimg.Filename and just Filename.

Comment: Can you edit your post for god shake ... pls

Comment: Which table does fileName belong to?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue lies somewhere in mismatching parentheses. Chances are your big select statement doesn't directly see the created table `rimg`.

Comment: If missing parantheses were the issue then it woulnd't run at all, but it works fine if I omit the Filename field from the main field list.  The Filename field belongs to recipe_image...it's the second JOIN. 

Thx for formatting my SQL :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in how you've used your parentheses to group your table, as well as the fact that you never select filename in the inner join.

The first big join, which you've named `r` is the table that has reference to `filename`. No where in that table do you select `rimg.fileName` so in the outer query, you can't even call `r.fileName`. To fix it, change the line:

```
SELECT r.ID, RecipeName
```

To:

```
SELECT r.ID, RecipeName, rimg.FileName
```

Then, in your outer query, you can select `r.FileName`.